# c# asynchronous http request

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, asynchronous

I am trying to make asynchronous call to some server so that the main thread does not stop for the request.

I created my request something like this :

```
//Create Request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "application/XML";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        try
        {
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // Send the data.
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            request.BeginGetResponse((x) =>
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(x))
                {
                    if (callback != null)
                    {
                        callback(response.GetResponseStream());
                    }
                }
            }, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Log error
        }
```

But still the thread stops for some time in this request. Especially on the line using

```
(Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
```

Is there any way by which we can make it completely asynchronous or some other better way so that our main thread does not hangs for this request.

Comment: Sure - call [GetRequestStreamAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststreamasync(v=vs.110).aspx) and await the result.

Comment: Or just use `HttpClient` and `await` if you can - it's much more concise.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx) says that if you call `GetRequestStream` then you *must* call `GetResponse` to get the response. If you want an asynchronous response using `BeginGetResonse`, then you *must* call `BeginGetRequeststream` to get the request stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: I am little confused here. In the request we actually wait for the response by putting await. Also if method A() makes the request then we have to call by await task A() and then wait for the response. Making it synchronous only.

Comment: @user2692032 [What Happens in an Async Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the async methods and await them.

```
using (var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample which I am using to make async request. Mark your method with `async keyword`

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    string requestContent = string.Empty; // JSON Content comes here
    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(Verb, url);
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpRequestMessage.Content = request.Verb == HttpMethod.Get ? null : httpContent;
    response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    var responseContent = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

}